# Can you get the cube of a rational number as a value of c in Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I did $a^3 +a^3 = b^3$, where $a$ is a rational or an integer, could you ever get a value where $b^3 =\frac{ x^3}{y^3} $ where $x$ and $y$ are integers? I saw somewhere else that you can get rational answers when you do FLT when $n>2$ just not integer. I was wondering if there was any way you can get an answer where b is rational rational when you do $2a^3$. Unfortunately, I've not done very much number theory and can't figure this out myself. Any help would be very appreciated. <3

Oh also what should I learn before learning number theory. I'm doing A level Maths and Further Maths right now, and I'd like to know what to learn before I can start number theory.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem applies to integers and rationals: if there was a rational counter-example, you could turn it into an integer counter-example since $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n +\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^n = \left(\frac{e}{f}\right)^n$ would imply $(adf)^n+(cbf)^n = (ebd)^n$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Alternative approach: $~a~$ is rational and $~\sqrt[3]{2}~$ is irrational.  Therefore $~b = \sqrt[3]{2} \times a~$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2):

If you got a solution of $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for rational a, b and c, you would just multiply all numbers with the smallest common multiple of the denominators and have an integer solution. Which doesn’t exist, therefore no rational solution.